# Слова "медюристы" и "Росинкас" вызывают у меня недоумение, кажется, что нужен дополнительный разделитель. Я бы поставил "ъ"

Tags: орфография

Правильно ли написаны слова без разделителя? Медюристы или медъюристы, Росинкас (росинка) или Росъинкас?

Answer (score 1):

В сложносокращённых словах не используются разделительные Ъ и Ь.
(См. [справочник Розенталя, примечание к пункту 1](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=31#pp31).)

Comment: Жуть! Я не сразу понял Росинка С. На машине прочитал.

Comment: @Владимир в нулевых был предложен Лопатиным проект реформы орфографии, где (среди прочего) была здравая идея разрешить писать прекрасно слышимые разделители: инъяз, минъюст и т. п. Но проект не был принят, реакционная публика не оценила "покушения на язык" (впрочем, ничего нового).